# SQL query (Sort by multiple columns)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem writing a specific query for my database
I have a table with the following records:

```
[ID(PK),Writer,Title,Year,Description]
```

. I want to sort the records first per year and secondly per Writer for every Starting Letter(A-Z). So Have a result as this

```
Year     Writer  Title
1999       A1      X
1999       A1      Y
2001       A2      V
2002       A1      Z
1991       B1      P
2002       B2      Q
2003       B1      R
```

So at the end will be years at ASC form for every Letter of the Alphabet (Writer ASC)!

Comment: In your result 1991 comes after 2002. How is this sorted by year?

Comment: Also other than your try what are the original data to be sorted ?

Comment: I want to sort first by year 1991-2002 and then by Name for every Name

Answer (score 1):

> SELECT YEAR, WRITER, TITLE ORDER BY YEAR, WRITER;

Something like this will sort by writer within year.

Comment: @androidgame2014 okay.. but ur question shows something different.. just opposite.

Comment: Right androidgame2014, like @Deepak Sharma said if that's what you meant to write.

Answer (score 0):

@Larz Plutzin..

he want the record to be sort first by author then by year.  check what he posted..

your query going to be like -  may be he could not explain the written what he wants. but the result he wanted going to be like this only..

> SELECT YEAR, WRITER, TITLE ORDER BY WRITER, YEAR;